# Asp .net MVC...HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage is not always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want upload an Image but it always gets null. I'm using `HttpPostedFileBase`.

This is my COntroller

```
public ActionResult EmployeeDetail(EmployeeModel employee, HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage)//this UploadImage Object is always null
{

    EmployeeModel employeeModel = new EmployeeModel();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeModel.Name))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Name is Required");
    }
    employeeModel.Name = employee.Name;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeModel.DOJ))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("DOJ", "DOJ is Requird");
    }
    employeeModel.DOJ = employee.DOJ;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeModel.DOB))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("DOB", "DOB is Required");
    }
    employeeModel.DOB = employee.DOB;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeModel.Designation))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Designation", "Designation is required");
    }
    employeeModel.Designation = employee.Designation;

    string ImageName = Path.GetFileName(UploadImage.FileName);
    string Physicalpath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);
    UploadImage.SaveAs(Physicalpath);
    employee.UploadImage = Physicalpath;

    //string ImageName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
    //string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);
    //image.SaveAs(physicalPath);


    //     ModelState.AddModelError("UploadImage", "upload   is required");
    //employee.UploadImage = physicalPath;
        EmployeeBusinessLayer employeeBL = new EmployeeBusinessLayer();
        employeeBL.InsertDataRegistration(employeeModel);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This is my View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeDetail", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @data_ajax = "false" })) //i have used all the codes which could be need to make it work...still not working
{  

<div class="MainDiv">
    <table class="Table">
        <tr class="Row">
            <td class="Column1"> Name</td>
            <td class="Column2">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Row">
            <td class="Column1">DOJ </td>
            <td class="Column2">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOJ, new { @class = "datepicker", autocomplete = "off" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="Row">
            <td class="Column1">DOB</td>
            <td class="Column2">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, new { @class = "datepicker", autocomplete = "off" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Row">
            <td class="Column1">DESIGNATION</td>
            <td class="Column2">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Designation) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Row">
            <td class="Column1">UPlOAD </td>
            <td class="Column2">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UploadImage, new { @type = "File"  })  
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Row">
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="button1" value="Clear" name="Clear">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/development-bundle/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        })
    </script>
</div>
}
```

this is my Model

```
public Model
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "this is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
    public string DOJ { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="This is required")]
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="This is required")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
    public string UploadImage { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase MyFile { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere you are passing any parameter to EmployeeDetail(). Are you able to get data for your EmployeeModel? If yes, then that at least confirm that your view able to call the EmployeeDetail() action.

Next, you need to make sure you are passing proper parameter to your EmployeeDetail(). One of the way I could think of is to use ajax. So you can create an ajax call when submit button is clicked, and pass all your data and the uploaded file input in the ajax method.

This is an example of using ajax call with JQuery syntax to pass data to the action

```
var inputFiles = $('inpFile').val();
var actMethod = "@Url.Action("EmployeeDetail", "Index")"
var postData = {
   "Name": $('inpName').val(),
   "DOJ": $('inpDOJ').val(),
   ...
   "UploadImage": inputFiles 
}
$.ajax()
{
     url: actMethod ,
     data: postData,
     type: "POST",
     success: function (data) {
        alert("Insert Successful!");
     }
}
```